# How to remove stored keychain details from amazon iOS cognito SDK

Tags: objective-c, amazon-cognito

I am using [CognitoAuth Sample](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples/tree/master/CognitoAuth-Sample) to implement sign-in and sign-out using AWS iOS SDK.

I have a signout button inside my app. When I click the button I need to clear the keychain details instead of calling the signout block and showing the safari view controller. Is there any way to do so? The only thing I could see to do was using the signout block, but I don't want this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Now the API is exposed by Amazon iOS Cognito for above ask.

Comment: Which API is exposed by amazon iOS Cognito for this?

Comment: @Harshavardhan, This is pretty old thread, I remembered signOutLocallyAndClearLastKnownUser and signOutLocally are exposed as public methods. But you need to check, last worked on library around 2019.